# What HTTP status fits a "3rd party authentication required" condition?

Tags: http, response, http-status-codes

We have a form submit in our application that requires a 3rd party authentication (through SMS) for some cases. What HTTP code would be ideal for this situation that can be described as:

"The form might or might not be fine, but we need you to first get your phone number verified (not authenticated)"

We are torn between:

- 202:Accepted
- 412:Precondition failed
- 428:Precondition Required

Answer (score 0):

In my mind if request is ok  http code should be 2xx. 
Http codes in 4xx familly mean that  user request is wrong. It's not your case, It's just step 1 / 2.

Comment: Agreed. We ended up using 202 in the end

Answer (score -1):

We ended up using **202** as it fit better than the rest.

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed

This made most sense, as we accept the form, but may or may not accept the request until it passes verification